# Program that takes a sentence and outputs # of vowels, consonants, etc

Tags: c++

```
enter code here 
int main()
{

std::string input;
std::cin >> input;

while (input != "quit")
{
// do stuff
std::cin >> input; // get another input

}

return EXIT_SUCCESS; // if we get here the input was quit
```

The problem is, it isn't prompting the user to enter words at all. If I enter "quit", it ends, so that's working fine. Otherwise, if I enter in anything else, then enter quit, it just quits as well. What should I do to rectify that?

Through my research, I was able to find a similar program here which uses case, but that seems a bit tedious to me. I have been instructed to use the isalpha function, which accepts a single character as a parameter and returns a Boolean indicator as to whether or not the character is a letter.

Comment: Please make your title relevant to the question you're actually attempting to ask (whatever that may be.)

Comment: Need to use `std::cout` somewhere - I guess

Comment: Instead of `cin` try using `getline(..)`.

Comment: My guess is that "do stuff" is not doing the right stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Try this small illustrative program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(void)
{
  std::cout << "This is a prompt, enter some text:\n";
  std::string  the_text;
  std::getline(std::cout, the_text); // Input the text.
  std::cout << "\n"
            << "The text you entered:\n";
  std::cout << the_text;
  std::cout << "\n";

  // Pause the program, if necessary.
  std::cout << "\n\nPaused.  Press Enter to continue...\n";
  std::cin.ignore(10000000, '\n');

  // Return status to the Operating System
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see, outputting an instructional phrase before an input is known as *prompting the User*.

**Edit 1:  Prompting in a `while` loop**
In your case, you need to prompt the user before the input:

```
while (input != "quit")
{
  // Do stuff

  std::cout << "Enter text or \"quit\" to quit: ";
  std::cout.flush();  // Flush buffers to get the text on the screen.
  std::cin >> input;
}
```